# How to change values in facet to same in Google Refine?

Tags: facet, google-refine

I'm trying to clean this data: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/820037/local_council_election_data_w_occupation.gz

It's all the candidates for a local councils' election in Finland. In the column "Ammatti" there is the occupation of a candidate as reported by him/her.

I want to find all the students, but the problem is, that they can be "opiskelija" (student) or "yliopisto-opiskelija" (university student) and things like that.

I clicked the column title "Ammatti" and Filtered it with "opiskelija", then I created a "text facet" from the menu in column title.

That gives me the following facet:

- agrol. opiskelija AMK 1
- agrologiopiskelija    9
- agronomiopiskelija    1

...and so on.

I'd want to change the value of "Ammatti" (occupation) to "opiskelija" (student) in everyone of these occasions.

To make thngs a bit more complicated the facet has also some occupations (mature students and administrative staff) I don't want to change to "opiskelija":

- aikuisopiskelija  10
- opiskelijakunnan hallituksen varapuheenjohtaja    1
- opiskelijapalvelun päällikkö  1
- opiskelijapalvelupäällikkö    1

I did this by hand clicking through the whole list in the facet and changing the occupations one by one.

I suppose there is a better way to do this, but could someone please tell me how I should've done it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'include' option in the facet, select all the rows that you want to transform from the column "Ammatti". Then in for this column invoke the Transform function and replace "value" by "opiskelija"

This will replace all the value you have selected by "opiskelija".

Hope this help (and it doesn't come too late).